# (CLOSED) How to fix Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gson

I have encountered a problem when I want to fetch my data to `recyclerview` using Java, and resulting in the problem:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:  Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

My API Response :

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "Barang Elektronik",
        "payment_method": "Cash",
        "price": "500000",
        "date": "2023-07-11 00:00:00",
        "detail": "Charger HP"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "Bahan Makanan",
        "payment_method": "Cash",
        "price": "50000",
        "date": "2023-07-11 02:49:57",
        "detail": "Mie Goreng 1 Dus"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "Kecantikan",
        "payment_method": "Gopay",
        "price": "120000",
        "date": "2023-07-11 00:00:00",
        "detail": "Skincare"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "type": "Lainnya",
        "payment_method": "Debit",
        "price": "1200000",
        "date": "2023-07-11 00:00:00",
        "detail": "Liburan"
    }
]
```

ApiInterface.java

```
@GET("api/index.php?route=expenses")
Call<AllExpenseResponse> getAllExpenseItem(@Query("id") String userID);
```

and the file that I have from generated POJO extension is:
AllExpenseResponse.java

```
package hafizcaniago.my.id.papb_final.Data.Response.Expenses;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AllExpenseResponse{

    @SerializedName("AllExpenseResponse")
    private List<AllExpenseResponseItem> allExpenseResponse;

    public List<AllExpenseResponseItem> getAllExpenseResponse(){
        return allExpenseResponse;
    }
}
```

AllExpenseResponseItem.java

```
package hafizcaniago.my.id.papb_final.Data.Response.Expenses;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AllExpenseResponseItem{

    @SerializedName("date")
    private String date;

    @SerializedName("price")
    private String price;

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("detail")
    private String detail;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("payment_method")
    private String paymentMethod;

    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }

    public String getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getDetail(){
        return detail;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public String getPaymentMethod(){
        return paymentMethod;
    }
}
```

and this is MainActivity.java in load RecyclerView

```
RestClient.getService().getAllExpenseItem(USER_ID).enqueue(new Callback<AllExpenseResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllExpenseResponse> call, Response<AllExpenseResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    expenseItem = response.body().getAllExpenseResponse();

                    Log.i("responseExpense", expenseItem.toString());

                    adapter = new ExpenseAdapter(expenseItem, getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllExpenseResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Wrong, Check Log for Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("error", t.toString());
                Log.i("error", call.toString());
            }
        });
```

I see some problem like that, but I don't still get it, what I must do. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type of your api function to :

```
 @GET("api/index.php?route=expenses")
 Call<List<AllExpenseResponseItem>> getAllExpenseItem(@Query("id") String userID);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i try and work. but i prefer to  change  the response api to make things easier for me.